# updating x and ylab within a loop using ggplot2

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I want to plot (scatterplot) all the posible combinations between the variables without repetition (correlation between the same variable) with the data from iris dataset. I thought that a loop would be of help for me and this code does what I want but only partially:

```
head(iris)
iris = iris[,c(1:4)]
n = ncol(iris)
for(j in 2:n) {
  for(i in j:n) {
    x = iris[,j-1][iris[,i]!=-99]
    y = iris[,i][iris[,i]!=-99]
    plot(x,y,type="n") 
    points(x,y,pch=1,col="gray50")
    lines(loess.smooth(x,y),lwd=2,col="blue")
  }
}
```

However, I am nor able to print the real name of the variables (e.g. Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, ...) instead of x and y.

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Could the solution be done using ggplot instead of the plot function?

Thank you very much in advance,

Best regards,

Mario

Comment: Your code does not use ggplot2 at all; you are using base graphics. The base `plot()` function has `xlab=` and `ylab=` parameters to set the axis labels. You can get variable names with `xlab=names(iris)[i]`.

Comment: The `pairs` function might be of interest to you. `pairs(iris, lower.panel=panel.smooth)`. Check this out for some more info including ggplot2 usage... (http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2011/07/scatterplot-matrices-in-r.html)